# Is there any way of a program running more than once in python

Tags: python

I have this code that only run once. Can anyone please help me to loop this particular code to run indefinitely?
Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```py
    def get_non_negative_int(prompt):
        while True:
            try:
                value = int(input(prompt))
            except ValueError:
                print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
                continue

            if value < 0:
                print("Sorry, your response must not be negative.")
                continue
            else:
                break
        return value

    age = get_non_negative_int("Please enter your age: ")

    kids = get_non_negative_int("Please enter the number of children you have: ")
```

Comment: Since your code contains `while True:` I would assume you already know how to loop "indefinitely", no? ;)

Comment: not really I just used a code a find here but couldn't run indefinitely that is why I posted it here but no one seems to work this one out  for this particular code or it is just too easy for everyone else but me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking that your program should load again after positive values are given as input then you simply have to add a `while` loop.

```
while(True):
  age = get_non_negative_int("Please enter your age: ")
  kids = get_non_negative_int("Please enter the number of children you have: ")
```

this will run indefinitely.

Comment: I didn't work in this particular code

Comment: I have tried to recreate the program and was successfully able to achieve the goal, are there any particular values that make this code not work indefinitely?

Comment: the whole code runs ok but when changed to your suggestion it didn't work. Do you managed to run the whole program with your addition? Could you please send me the whole code.